# Swift Undefined OBJC Class symbol

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I am trying to build and run my project on the simulator, but am getting this error from an AppsFlyer library:

`Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerLib`

Building and running on a physical device works fine, only get the error when trying on simulator.

I've tried `pod install --repo-update`, I've tried clean and build, I've tried deleting derived data, I've tried quitting Xcode and rebooting. Nothing helped. What is the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 12.4 by any chance?  See [this issue](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/AppsFlyerFramework/issues/171).

Comment: @trojanfoe I am currently using Xcode 13, but I've definitely had the same issue using previous versions of Xcode